# date timestamps not matching / merging properly in R

Tags: r, datetime, utc

I have two data frames:

locA:

```
Date    Time    Temperature Voltage Longitude   Latitude    Deployment  DateTime
2014-08-08  14:18:25    20.9    1.872   -126.6886   34.95633    A   2014-08-08 14:20:00
2014-08-08  14:38:25    19.8    1.862   -126.6899   34.95675    A   2014-08-08 14:40:00
2014-08-08  14:58:26    19.3    1.856   -126.6911   34.95732    A   2014-08-08 15:00:00
2014-08-08  15:18:26    18.8    1.872   -126.6921   34.95803    A   2014-08-08 15:20:00
2014-08-08  15:38:25    18.6    1.872   -126.6929   34.95872    A   2014-08-08 15:40:00
2014-08-08  15:58:26    18.4    1.859   -126.6937   34.95921    A   2014-08-08 16:00:00
2014-08-08  16:18:25    18.4    1.875   -126.6944   34.95983    A   2014-08-08 16:20:00
2014-08-08  16:38:25    18.4    1.875   -126.6949   34.96021    A   2014-08-08 16:40:00
2014-08-08  16:58:26    18.4    1.872   -126.6956   34.96033    A   2014-08-08 17:00:00
2014-08-08  17:18:26    18.4    1.872   -126.6962   34.96025    A   2014-08-08 17:20:00
```

and datA:

```
FileName    Deployment  Start_UTC   Stop_UTC    Duration    sum PrAb    dolPrAb
DASBR1_20140808$140000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:00:00 2014-08-08 14:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$142000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:20:00 2014-08-08 14:22:00 119.6000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$144000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:40:00 2014-08-08 14:42:00 119.8000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$150000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:00:00 2014-08-08 15:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$152000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:20:00 2014-08-08 15:22:00 119.6000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$154000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:40:00 2014-08-08 15:42:00 119.6000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$160000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:00:00 2014-08-08 16:02:00 119.6000    1   1   1
DASBR1_20140808$162000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:20:00 2014-08-08 16:22:00 119.8000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$164000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:40:00 2014-08-08 16:42:00 119.8000    0   0   0
DASBR1_20140808$170000.wav  A   2014-08-08 17:00:00 2014-08-08 17:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0
```

Each are actually several thousand rows long.  I want to merge them based on the "DateTime" stamp in locA and the "Start_UTC" in datA.  Both of those columns have been formatted identically in UTC.

```
locA$DateTime=as.POSIXct(paste(locA$Date, time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
datA$Start_UTC = as.POSIXct(files$Start_UTC, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
```

In locA, the "time" variable comes from a sequence where I round the character string in locA$Time to the nearest 20min.  "time" is a character string with the adjusted time.

```
str(time)
chr [1:8845] "14:00:00" "14:20:00" "14:40:00" "15:00:00" "15:20:00" "15:40:00" "16:00:00" "16:20:00" "16:40:00" "17:00:00" ...
```

When I merge the two data frames using locA$DateTime and datA$Start_UTC, it never works properly.  I get something that looks like this, every time.

```
resA = merge(datA,locA, by.x=c("Start_UTC"), by.y=c("DateTime"))
```

resA:

```
Start_UTC   FileName    Deployment.x    Stop_UTC    Duration    sum PrAb    dolPrAb Date    Time    Temperature Voltage Longitude   Latitude    Deployment.y
2014-08-08 14:00:00 DASBR1_20140808$140000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  20:58:26    19.1    1.872   -126.7018   34.94994    A
2014-08-08 14:20:00 DASBR1_20140808$142000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:22:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  21:18:26    19.1    1.872   -126.7027   34.94801    A
2014-08-08 14:40:00 DASBR1_20140808$144000.wav  A   2014-08-08 14:42:00 119.8000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  21:38:26    19.1    1.872   -126.7038   34.94608    A
2014-08-08 15:00:00 DASBR1_20140808$150000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  21:58:27    18.9    1.865   -126.7050   34.94394    A
2014-08-08 15:20:00 DASBR1_20140808$152000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:22:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  22:18:27    18.9    1.856   -126.7062   34.94188    A
2014-08-08 15:40:00 DASBR1_20140808$154000.wav  A   2014-08-08 15:42:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  22:38:26    18.8    1.862   -126.7077   34.93994    A
2014-08-08 16:00:00 DASBR1_20140808$160000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:02:00 119.6000    1   1   1   2014-08-08  22:58:26    18.8    1.859   -126.7090   34.93796    A
2014-08-08 16:20:00 DASBR1_20140808$162000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:22:00 119.8000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  23:18:26    18.8    1.865   -126.7105   34.93622    A
2014-08-08 16:40:00 DASBR1_20140808$164000.wav  A   2014-08-08 16:42:00 119.8000    0   0   0   2014-08-08  23:38:27    18.6    1.856   -126.7120   34.93480    A
2014-08-08 17:00:00 DASBR1_20140808$170000.wav  A   2014-08-08 17:02:00 119.6000    0   0   0   2014-08-09  23:58:28    18.8    1.849   -126.8051   34.88381    A
```

I have tried this so many different ways.  I tried keeping the locA$DateTime as is, where the time equals the time stamp in datA$Time, and then tried using this function to match it to the correct datA$Start_UTC.  Match the minimum locA$timestamp to the datA$timestamp

```
findrow=function(dt,df) {min(which(df>dt))}
rowA=sapply(locA$DateTime, findrow, df=datA$Start_UTC)
resA=cbind(locA,datA[rowA,])
```

This gave me the same results.  I don't know what's going on.  I'm sure it's intrinsic to how the datetime stamps are generated, but I don't know how to fix this.  If I format them the same, and tell R that they are UTC, shouldn't they be treated the same way?

Help, please, all help, comments, or humorous "hang in there" statements would greatly appreciated. Not being able to properly pair my lat/longs with my data timestamps is really causing a headache.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if doing a merge on chr objects instead of POSIXct objects would work better?

```
locA$DateTime_str = format(locA$DateTime)
datA$Start_UTC_str = format(datA$Start_UTC)
resA = merge(datA,locA, by.x=c("Start_UTC_str"), by.y=c("DateTime_str"))
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, though in general I can't understand why the timestamps don't work.  I think a character string may be the best round-about way, though.